# Box Layout components move when button is visible and invisible

Tags: java, swing, layout, boxlayout

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

.....

JPanel centrePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(10, 0));

........

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 160));

centrePanel.add(glListScrollPane);

........

........


JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

......

........

panel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

panel.add(centrePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

panel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.add(panel);

frame.add(standardButtonPanel);


public void lockScreen(boolean editable) {

standardButtonPanel.button1.setVisible(editable);

......

}
```

When doing edit and un-edit. the panel is changing its position a little bit. 
I have used BoxLayout as I wanted to have the components have there own size and users can resize the screen also. 
Is there any other approach? Where I can fix the layout problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setVisible`, try using `setEnabled` as it dosent hide the button (hence does not affect the UI) but makes it so that the end-user cannot press the button.

Comment: We have standard buttons and same functionality all across the product, I can't changed this functionality. Now I have tried    panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue()); but it also did not help.